# Terraform value is not suitable

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have an error when trying to apply, but I can't find the issue.

The error is

> Error: Invalid value for input variable
> │
> │   on main.tf line 42, in module "lb_tg_attachment":
> │   42:     instance_id                         = module.ec2.instance_id
> │
> │ The given value is not suitable for module.lb_tg_attachment.var.instance_id declared at ../../resources/lb_tg/attach/variables.tf:2,1-23: string
> │ required.

Trying to create EC2, Target group and attach the created instances to the target group.

Module code:

```
# Creating EC2 instance
module "ec2" {
    source                  = "../../resources/ec2"
    region                  = var.region
    access_key              = var.access_key
    secret_key              = var.secret_key
    ami                     = var.ami
    instance_type           = var.instance_type
    iam_instance_profile    = var.iam_instance_profile
    security_groups         = var.security_groups
    tags                    = var.tags
    key_name                = var.key_name
    user_data               = var.user_data
    # private_ip              = var.private_ip
    subnet_id               = var.subnet_id
    server_count            = var.server_count
}

# Creating target group
module "lb_tg" {
    depends_on = [ module.ec2 ]
    source                              = "../../resources/lb_tg/tg"
    target_type                         = var.target_type
    name                                = var.group_name
    protocol                            = var.protocol
    port                                = var.port
    vpc_id                              = var.vpc_id
    health_check_port                   = var.health_check_port
    health_check_protocol               = var.health_check_protocol
    health_check_interval               = var.health_check_interval
    health_check_timeout                = var.health_check_timeout
    health_check_path                   = var.health_check_path
    health_check_healthy_threshold      = var.health_check_healthy_threshold
    health_check_unhealthy_threshold    = var.health_check_unhealthy_threshold
    tags                                = var.tag_tg
}

# Attaching instance to the target group
module "lb_tg_attachment" {
    source                              = "../../resources/lb_tg/attach"
    depends_on                          = [ module.lb_tg ]
    instance_id                         = module.ec2.instance_id
    register_targets_port               = var.register_targets_port
    aws_lb_target_group_arn             = module.lb_tg.aws_lb_target_group_arn
}
```

EC2 resource:

```
# EC2 Instance
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  count                   = var.server_count
  ami                     = var.ami
  instance_type           = var.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile    = var.iam_instance_profile
  security_groups         = var.security_groups
  tags                    = var.tags
  key_name                = var.key_name
  user_data               = var.user_data
  # private_ip              = var.private_ip[count.index]
  subnet_id               = var.subnet_id
}

output "instance_id" {
  value       = [aws_instance.ec2.*.id]
  description = "ID of the EC2 instance"
}

output "instance_arn" {
  value = [aws_instance.ec2.*.arn]
  description = "ARN of the EC2 instance"
}

output "availability_zone" {
  value       = [aws_instance.ec2.*.availability_zone]
  description = "ID of the EC2 Availability_Zone"
}
```

Target group resource:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "lb_tg" {
  target_type = var.target_type
  name = var.name
  protocol = var.protocol
  port = var.port
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  health_check {
    port = var.health_check_port
    protocol = var.health_check_protocol
    interval = var.health_check_interval
    timeout = var.health_check_timeout
    path = var.health_check_path
    healthy_threshold = var.health_check_healthy_threshold
    unhealthy_threshold = var.health_check_unhealthy_threshold
  }
  tags = var.tags
}
```

Attach resource:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "lb_tg_attachment" {
  target_group_arn  = var.aws_lb_target_group_arn
  target_id         = var.instance_id
  port              = var.register_targets_port
}
```

Changing the ec2 output didn't help.